# media queris в js

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть slick slider и там есть некоторые значения

```
$('.portfolio-slider').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '128px',
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
```

как мне сделать что бы до размера `720px` `centerMode` менялся на `false` и `slideToShow` менялся на `1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.portfolio-slider').slick({
centerMode: true,
centerPadding: '128px',
dots: false,
infinite: true,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [
      {
          breakpoint: 720,
          settings: {
              centerMode: false,
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              infinite: true,
              dots: false
          }
      }
  ]
```

});